# Strange equation on notebook

Tags: soft-question

It could sound like a silly question, but I found this equation written in my notebook and never knew what was the meaning and who wrote it. I think it could be related to some physics equation, and that's why I'm adding it here, but please tell my if it is off topic. Can you interpret it?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about deciphering an equation and not physics.

Comment: I understand the off-topic but could have been a physics equation and I didn't know. Do you suggest another exchange channel? Would be off-topic also in math? I'd really like to know if it have a meaning. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second term on the left has what looks like a square root symbol with nothing underneath.

The first term has an integral sign with no measure.

The second character in the second and third terms is not a symbol I've ever seen (though it is slightly similar to a capital sigma, $\Sigma$.)

I highly doubt that it is an actual mathematical statement, at least not with any symbol set I've seen. My first guess is that it's just someone writing down mathematical symbols that look cool. I have certainly done that before.

It might also be some sort of code or joke that uses math symbols instead of letters like leet-speak. But nothing stands out to me.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I had the same thoughts than you. Btw I'm an engineer and I really don't know why this equations appeared on my notebook. It is even stranger, because the equation is written twice (as noted by the different kind of writings). Here is the complete image if you are interested :) http://imgur.com/oOMESMx thanks!